# Can I use a different file structure in azure app services?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a python flask API in azure app services. When deploying to it from vs code, I get a "successful deployment" message, but the app still shows the default initial web page provided as a template from Microsoft for new app services.

The current file structure looks something like this:

```
├───README.md
├───docs
├───data
└───src
    ├───main.py
    └───other_files.py
```

I changed the file structure to look like the following:

```
├───README.md
├───docs
├───data
├───app.py
└───src
    └───other_files.py
```

After deploying it like this, the application was able to start normally instead of displaying the boilerplate webpage from Microsoft. What do I need to do to have the `app.py` inside the `src` directory?

Can it actually be done?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it on my own by providing a custom startup command in the configuration of the app service. It can be done from the azure portal, in the "Configuration" section, or with the azure CLI.

```
az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --startup-file "<custom-command>"
```

And the custom command was:

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir src main:app
```

More details of this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-startup-command